# SQL Server: Most optimal way of storing time (without date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's one more or less for perfection's sake.

Microsoft SQL Server only contains the field type `datetime` for storing dates and times.

But let's say that I want to store a list of business hours, where the date is completely irrelevant. Currently I'm using the `datetime` type and then simply displaying the time-portion of the data. But I have two problems with this.

1. It seems awkwardly inefficient.
2. It may confuse future developers to see a full-blown date coming along with the time, which they may not know whether is used anywhere or not.

And so it begs the question; in the absence of a specific `time` field (like in MySQL), what is the most optimal way of storing only a particular time of day, from 00:00 to 23:59?

**UPDATE**: It's SQL Server 2005. (Also I'd just be interested in knowing what to do in general when there is no `time` type.)

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2008 or later (crossing fingers) because then you can just use the Time datatype.

Comment: SQL Server 2008+ has a time datatype:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: SQL Server did introduce a [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) datatype in 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For SQL Server 2005 or older...**

If you only want to know to the minute, you can store it as an int in the range of `1-1440`.  `1` is 00:01 and `1440` is `0:00`.

It would be easy do display as a time again if you like:

`SELECT CAST((605 / 60) as varchar) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((605 % 60) as varchar), 2)`

An additional advantage of this is that if you use a `smallint` data type you are saving 1-3 bytes per record from the built-in `TIME` datatype.

`TIME` uses 3-5 bytes per row and `smallint` is 2 bytes per row.

The extra bytes are for seconds and fractional seconds I believe.

**EDIT**

It's more complicated with seconds but still doable I should think...

1-86400 range (seconds per day)

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 3661

SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST((@i / 3600) as varchar),2) --hours
+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((@i % 3600)/60 as varchar), 2) -- minutes
+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((@i % 3600)%60 as varchar), 2) -- seconds
```

Comment: Interesting. What if I wanted hours, minutes and seconds, do you know?

Comment: I'd use the range `0 to n-1`; midnight is normally considered the first instant at the start of the day, rather than the last instant at the end of a day.  (It does depend on the case in point, but this is significantly more normal in my experience.)

Comment: @Dems - the range is actually irrelevant to the logic, but excellent point.

Comment: If your concern is for future maintenance however, this is a poor solution.  Full blown datetime will be much more obvious.  I'd use this only if required.

Comment: @tricky - Agreed, this is basically a hack to get what OP was asking for - efficient way to store time only data without a time datatype.

Comment: Yeah, it has become a trade-off question at this point. It's very interesting though, thanks for the excellent answer!

Comment: I just tested it, and it works beautifully.

Well, I had to change the "DECLARE @i" bit, but that was it. I took the liberty to edit your post accordingly, so now it works straight out of the box on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Helgi - happy to help and  thanks for editing the answer to clarify what worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2008 has a `TIME` datatype:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/datetime-2008/

```
DECLARE @dt as TIME
SET @dt = getdate()
PRINT @dt
```

Upgrade to SQL 2008?

Comment: +1 SQL Server 2005 has had its "end of life" already - definitely time to upgrade!

Comment: You know how it works with commercial, closed-source software! Cost of ownership doesn't matter until you have to upgrade. ;)

Answer (score 2):

[MS SQL Server 2008 time data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

Comment: This is only applicable in `SQL Server 2008` currently.

Comment: @JNK true, but Author didn't specify version requirement.

Comment: I know, but you just need to make sure to qualify that in these cases.  If version is not specified but your solution is version specific, mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would not consider the points raised as sufficient enough to move away from using DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME.

- An INT uses 4 bytes, as does a SMALLDATETIME
- People make mistakes with SMALLINT that cause implicit type conversions (increasing cpu load)
- Disk Space is cheap, you need a lot of bytes to add up to anythign significant
- Code such as `WHERE minutes < 720` is less understandable than `WHERE time < '12:00'`
- Display issues (such as conversion of DATETIME to hh:mm) is often best place in the client
- Using DATETIME allows future flexibility, such moving to seconds instead of minutes

That said, I have used INTEGER fields to hold number of seconds, such as when they're predominantly used for calculating average durations, etc.

My single biggest consideration in choosing the type is how the value will be used; to ensure legible code and performant execution plans.

Comment: +1 - All very valid points.  My point about the bytes in my answer is probably more related to my personal experience.  I have a lot of VERY large (600m-2b row) tables, and if I can shave off a few bytes per row it adds up quickly.

Comment: Very true, but there is a strong arguement that even 4GB is relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2008 fixed this problem as others have noted but in 2005:

Do you need to perform any date math on the times?  If not, you can store it as a string.

If you need to perform date math, a datetime with the day set to zero along with a descriptive column name shouldn't stump any future devs (and thanks for keeping us in mind).

And yes, datetime is clunky for time only storage but it functions just fine.